# como compartir datos entre componentes de Angular si tener que ser propiedades de los mismos

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando editar los valores de las columnas de una tabla y al hacer click en cada una de ellas abro un sat popover [sat popover](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ncstate/sat-popover)

El caso es que dentro del componente anidado yo necesito saber que tipo de columna es y para eso estoy a la espera de recibir ese valor en la variable origen

```
export class SelectEditComponent {
@Input()
value:string;

@Input()
origen:string;
```

Pero cuando intento enviarle ambos valores desde el componente contenedor me encuentro con este error

[image: error]

Es decir, ¿no puedo asignar a la variable Input del componente anidado un valor sin más, en este caso un string literal o debe ser una propiedad del componente padre?

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe ser:

`[origen]="'responsable'"`

> Notese las comillas simples.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está diciendo es que la variable `responsable` no existe en el componente de la imagen que compartes.

En Angular hay 2 maneras de definir el valor de las variables. Pongo un ejemplo con tu variable `origen`:

- Si pones `[origen]="responsable"` va a buscar una variable en tu componente que se llame `responsable`, y le pasará al otro componente el valor que tenga.
- Si pones `origen="responsable"` lo que le va a pasar al componente es una cadena con valor "responsable" (que creo que es lo que quieres hacer tú en este caso).

Espero que te pueda servir